# Compiling each class of the same project in one jar using maven

Tags: java, maven

I've implemented a software which recognizes .jar files in runtime. I have three requisites for the file to be recognized in the application. The first one is having a certain annotation created for that end. The second one is that the class compiled must inherit from certain class I've created and The third one is that a jar file only can contain that class.

Currently I deploy them manually (exporting them on eclipse) but the number of classes is growing and now I have to export like 120 classes (I don't have to export all the classes every time but sometimes i make major changes on the superclass and I have to)

The problem is: I have all the classes that I have to export separately in the same project. I've already configured a maven+jenkins server for the application which recognizes the jar and I would want to compile every class separately with a jenkins task. Is there any way of forcing Maven to deploy different files in one build with the same or different POMs?

Comment: Sounds like you need a multi module maven project with correct dependencies

Comment: This sounds like a strange approach. What problem are you trying to solve? Maybe we can find a Maven way for this. Usually, you have one Eclipse project per jar (if not using multi-module) and this contains the classes. Why do you need a special logic to "recognize classes"?

Comment: The classes are on a diferent project because of management and 'modularity' reasons (the bosses decided it). The software developed is used on different clients, so we deploy the classes compiled separately as jars, and we send them to the client. The files are copied in a folder and the generic project recognizes them as it were  plugins. The reasons are that multiple files can or cannot be in the same client and some updates sometimes have to be uploaded in one client but not in the others.